# ListView item showing wrong while scrolling android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to show some words in the `ListView`.But the problem is when i start to scroll `ListView` is not populating the next words.It populates randomly the same duplicated words.

**DictListAdapter:**

```
public class DictListViewAdapter extends BaseSwipeAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> searchResult;
    private String word;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    TextView wrd;

    public DictListViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String>searchResult) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.searchResult = searchResult;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    @Override
    public View generateView(final int position, ViewGroup parent,View v) {
           if(inflater==null){
               inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                       .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           }
           if(v==null) {
               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,null);
           }


        wrd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.word);
        final TextView meaning=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.meaning);

        SwipeLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout)v.findViewById(getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position));
        swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
               // YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(layout.findViewById(R.id.trash));
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, DatabaseHelper.getSingleMeaning(searchResult.get(position), mContext), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String mean=DatabaseHelper.getSingleMeaning(searchResult.get(position),mContext);
                meaning.setText(mean);
            }
        });
        swipeLayout.setOnDoubleClickListener(new SwipeLayout.DoubleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(SwipeLayout layout, boolean surface) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "DoubleClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        /*v.findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "click delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        */

        word = searchResult.get(position);
        wrd.setText(word);


        return v;
    }
```

This class extends `BaseSwipeAdapter` and it has the `getView()` method like below where it has the implementation of `getView()`:

```
    @Override
    public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            v = generateView(position, null,convertView);
        }
        mItemManger.bind(v, position);
        fillValues(position, v);
        return v;
    }
```

I know that **"Every time ListView needs to show a new row on screen, it will call the getView() method from its adapter."** That's why i added **if(v==null)** but not working.But i have done this tweak in my other projects.It worked fine then but in this project it's not working.Any Solution??Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I have tried using ViewHolder but not working.Did i miss anything??

```
static class ViewHolder {
        TextView wrd;
        int position;
    }

    public DictListViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String>searchResult) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.searchResult = searchResult;
    }




    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    @Override
    public View generateView(final int position, ViewGroup parent,View v) {
          ViewHolder viewHolder;
           if(inflater==null){
               inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                       .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           }
           if(v==null) {

               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,null);
               viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
               viewHolder.wrd=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.word);
               viewHolder.position=position;
               v.setTag(viewHolder);
           }else{
               viewHolder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
           }


        viewHolder.wrd.setText(searchResult.get(position));
        final TextView meaning=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.meaning);

        SwipeLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout)v.findViewById(getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position));
        swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
               // YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(layout.findViewById(R.id.trash));
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, DatabaseHelper.getSingleMeaning(searchResult.get(position), mContext), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String mean=DatabaseHelper.getSingleMeaning(searchResult.get(position),mContext);
                meaning.setText(mean);
            }
        });
        swipeLayout.setOnDoubleClickListener(new SwipeLayout.DoubleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(SwipeLayout layout, boolean surface) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "DoubleClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        /*v.findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "click delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        */

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `ViewHolder` pattern for `ListView`

Comment: why it is not working??Any tweak for this code??

Comment: you are not caching view so i suggest that use `ViewHolder` pattern

Comment: what are mItemManger.bind(v, position); and 
        fillValues(position, v); ?

Comment: i have applied ViewHolder pattern but not working..@Nilesh

Comment: I would be cool if you could observe what `searchResult.get(position)` inside `generateView` returns

Answer (score 1):

if you have to use ViewHolder pattern and check the null view inside the generateView methos then you will have to change the code inside BaseSwipeAdapter

```
@Override
public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    // if(v == null){

    v = generateView(position, v, parent);
    // }
    mItemManger.bind(v, position);
    fillValues(position, v);
    return v;
}
```

comment this null check and try now.